# mistakenly awarded a badge

Tags: support, status-bydesign, voting, reputation, badges

I down-voted a [discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6065/gnu-screen-new-window-name-change) in unix.SE by mistake (mouse moved when I went to click up-vote).  I already corrected my vote.  But I was awarded a badge unfairly.  How do I request to have the critic badge removed from my account?

Comment: Don't worry the first couple badges are kind of just trivial things that they throw around to get you used to the system. Do things, ear rep / get noted for it. Being a critic just means you are participating, which you obviously deserve for being here asking about it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is marked [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) on the main meta, in [Is the Critic badge badge awarded prematurely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2137/is-the-critic-badge-badge-awarded-prematurely). I wouldn't worry about it, you'll [find something to actually downvote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts?pagesize=15&filter=day) soon enough

Comment: Thank you, Michael.  I didn't think to check meta.stackexchange.